# Is $K=\{f_\lambda(x)=e^{\lambda x}\mid \lambda \in [0,a], x\in [0,b]\}$ equcontinuous?

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying prove that the following set is equcontinuous.

> $K=\{f_\lambda(x)=e^{\lambda x}\mid \lambda \in [0,a], x\in [0,b]\}$

I read two prove of equcontinuty in two theorem and twice of theme have the hypothesis of compactness. So I have no idea prove this without compactness. Please help me with Hints or similar.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid using compactness? $[0,a]\times[0,b]$ is compact.

Comment: How it can help me? I need the compactness of $K$ in that approach.

Comment: do you know that if the $f_\lambda$ are $C^1$ and their derivatives are uniformly bounded by some constant $C$ independant of $\lambda$, then they are equicontinuous ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $[0,a]\times[0,b]$ is compact the function $(\lambda,x) \longmapsto e^{\lambda x}$ is uniformly continuous. Hence we may choose $\delta$ so that $|x-y| + |\lambda_x-\lambda_y| < \delta$ implies $|e^{\lambda_x x} - e^{\lambda_y y}| < \epsilon$. Hence for any $\lambda$ take $\lambda_x=\lambda_y$ and if $|x-y|<\delta$ then $|f_\lambda(x)-f_\lambda(y)|<\epsilon$ which shows equicontinuity.

Answer (score 1):

Another one:  if you want to avoid saying "compact".  The derivative of $e^{\lambda x}$ is $\lambda e^{\lambda x}$.  The value of $e^{\lambda x}-e^{\lambda y}$ is that derivative at some point $\xi$ of $[0,b]$ times $(x-y)$.  So
$$
\left|e^{\lambda x} - e^{\lambda y}\right| = \lambda e^{\lambda \xi}|x-y|
\le a e^{ab} |x-y| .
$$
Can you see how to finish?

Comment: Yes I can. so thanks.